# VBA macro takes too long to execute

Tags: excel, vba

This very simple macro is taking 93 seconds just run through 55 iterations.  I also tried it as a for next loop, same result.

```
Dim thedate As Date
Dim current_cell As Long
Dim f As Single
f = Timer()

current_cell = Range("e65000").End(xlUp).Row

thedate = Range("e" & current_cell).Value
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do Until Range("f" & current_cell).Value = ""
i = i + 1
If i = 900 Then
End
End If

    If Range("g" & current_cell).Value <> "x" Then
    Cells(current_cell, "e").Value = thedate
    Else
    thedate = thedate + 1
    Cells(current_cell, "e").Value = thedate
    End If
current_cell = current_cell + 1

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "ET: " & Format(Timer - f, "0.000") & "s"
```

**FIRST UPDATE**

Ok, I looked at another page and they recommended using the with feature.  I did that and it still took me 28 seconds to loop through 15 cells.

```
Dim thedate As Date
Dim current_cell As Long
Dim f As Single
f = Timer()


current_cell = Range("e65000").End(xlUp).Row

Dim stop_working As Long
stop_working = Range("f65000").End(xlUp).Row - 1

thedate = Range("e" & current_cell).Value
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("time")

For k = current_cell To stop_working
i = i + 1
If i = 900 Then
End
End If

    If .Range("g" & current_cell).Value <> "x" Then
    .Cells(current_cell, "e").Value = thedate
    Else
    thedate = thedate + 1
    .Cells(current_cell, "e").Value = thedate
    End If
    current_cell = current_cell + 1

Next

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "ET: " & Format(Timer - f, "0.000") & "s"
```

**THIRD UPDATE**

Ok, I've done some research and I learned that you're not supposed to loop over ranges and that you're supposed to put the ranges in an array. I don't really understand this but I did try putting the cells into an array and using the for each feature. It still seems like I'm looping over ranges because whenever a step into the function it still noticeably takes a very long time to cross over the rng part of the code. My second problem is that none of the values are getting published on the screen. My third problem is that I'm getting a type mismatch with thedate. My fourth problem is that I don't understand the difference betwene value and value2.

```
Sub dates()


Dim thedate
Dim current_cell As Long
Dim f As Single
f = Timer()
Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range


current_cell = Range("e65000").End(xlUp).Row


Dim done As Long
done = Range("f65000").End(xlUp).Row - 1


Set rng = Range("g" & current_cell, "g" & done)
Set rng2 = Range("e" & current_cell, "e" & done)


thedate = Format(thedate, Date)
thedate = rng2.Value
'thedate = rng2.Value
Dim i As Integer
i = 7
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'With Sheets("time")


For Each cell In rng






    If cell.Value <> "x" Then
    rng2.Value = thedate
    Else
    thedate = thedate + 1
    rng2.Value = thedate
    End If



Next


'End With


'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "ET: " & Format(Timer - f, "0.000") & "s"
```

**4TH UPDATE**

I have a new code that works but it still take 78 seconds to run through 50 iterations.  Don't understand what the problem is.

```
Dim iRow As Long, erow As Long
erow = Cells(Rows.Count, "e").End(xlUp).Row
Dim thedate As Date
Dim f As Single
f = Timer()

    For iRow = erow To 35856
        If Cells(iRow, "G") = "x" Then

            Cells(iRow, "E").Value = Cells(iRow - 1, "E").Value + 1
        Else
            Cells(iRow, "E").Value = Cells(iRow - 1, "E").Value
        End If

    Next iRow

    MsgBox "ET: " & Format(Timer - f, "0.000") & "s"
End Sub
```

Comment: That would seem to be critically dependent on the worksheet data don't you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reduce runtime for code using ranges and string comparisons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423546/how-to-reduce-runtime-for-code-using-ranges-and-string-comparisons)

Comment: Why should it be dependent on the worksheet data?  All I'm doing is determining if there is an x in the g column cell?

Comment: @user147178 please read the suggested duplicate.  Answers to that question provide answers to yours.

Comment: see the edit I made to the OP

Comment: The salient point is: don't loop over a range, use a Variant Array

Comment: I don't see how I could not loop over a range. How do I put the info into an array if the info is stored in a range?

Comment: see the third edit I made to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I need to change calculation to manual and disable the firing of events.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

For iRow = 3 To Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(iRow, "G") = "x" Then
        Cells(iRow, "E").Value = Cells(iRow - 1, "E").Value + 1
    Else
        Cells(iRow, "E").Value = Cells(iRow - 1, "E").Value
    End If
Next iRow


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```